# c# ToString a decimal and force + sign AND number decimal places

Tags: c#, tostring

How can I do two things in tostring format:

```
1. Display number to x decimal places
2. Also force a + sign so that negative an positive numbers lineup in nice columns.

string fmt = "+N" + dp + ";-N" + dp;
Console.WrtieLine(Open.ToString(fmt))
```

Does not work?

Comment: "It doesn't work" is a lousy problem description, but clearly it is because you spelled WriteLine wrong.  Using a formatting string with # could be next.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to create a custom format string to do what you want. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx tells you about these but the below is a quick example of one thing that does the trick.

```
double num = 1111.019123;
int dp = 2;
string format = String.Format("+#.{0};-#.{0}",new string ('#',dp));
Console.WriteLine(num.ToString(format));
```

Comment: That's great - I changed it slightly and it does exactly what I wanted. Thanks - I never considered doing it this way.  

string fmt = String.Format("+0.{0};-0.{0}", new string('0', dp));

Comment: Cool. Glad it helped. Your only problem was that you were trying to use the standard format strings in the custom formatter which didn't work. All I did was put in the appropriate custom formats. :)